# FragmentTransaction.replace() arguments

Tags: android

I created a class called SlidingFragment that extends from Fragment, and in my MainActivity I put these lines:

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpView();
        setUpFragment();

    }
    void setUpView(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    void setUpFragment(){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingFragment fragment = new SlidingFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

The problem is that the replace() method of the FragmentTransaction class can't recognize the second argument fragment which is a SlidingFragment object. I get this:
**wrong second argument type found.'SlidingFragment' required 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'.
replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
to
replace(int,com.example.g514110.IhmSlidingTabs.SlidingFragment)**

I understand the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
Can someone please help.Thanks

Comment: can you add your SlidingFragment fragmnet?

Comment: is SlidingFragment extending the Fragment class?

Comment: Could it be that you are extending the Fragment class that is not from the support.v4?

Comment: Yes!! that was it!!Thanks

Comment: @DouaeHaddad can you mark my answer as correct then? :)

Answer (score 1):

Do that SlidingFragment extends

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and not

```
android.app.Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `SlidingFragment` is extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Based on this compiler error, it currently is not.

Answer (score 0):

Before I am also facing this issue , I did few changes . Now it's Workking Fine

New frgment page Eg :  home_fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Main XML Design must contain any layout with your id eg :

```
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
```

Main Java Class

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Click Event

```
home_fragment fragment = new home_fragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

This Code Workking Fine For Me